# Should these auxiliary files be under Git version control?

Tags: c++, git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I decided to start using the Git version control system for my C++ project. I'm new to version control.  For the trunk things are simple, I just commit all the project versions I have. I kept each version as a separate folder because I knew I'd very soon use Git. But I encountered a problem with my branches.

At some stage of the development, I decided there's one class I want to develop in a branch. Without version control, I had to use make a "manual" branch. I copied the most recent header file and source file of that class to a separate folder and started working there. I made several  versions there to work with simultaneously. One version was the first prototype of the class according to the plan (for which I made the "branch"). Then I added another file, in which I copied the first one but removed things that seemed to not be necessary. This way I have 2 versions, one with all my ideas and features, the the other one just with what I really use in my code, without what's not in use at the moment.

But then I added more. As development went on, I decided it may be a good idea to make that class a template. So I added a third version, which is just like the second one, but now some functionality implemented using polymorphism is implemented using a template. And I can't tell yet which version is the best, as it's too early to tell, so I want to have all 3 together.

Then I made another special file: A copy of the third version header file, in which each line can be marked or not marked. Marked means I use that specific method or I'm sure it's going to be in use very soon, otherwise the line isn't marked.

Then, some time later, I started a new branch. And for that branch I needed a new version of that class developed in the first branch. So I just copied one of the versions to the new branch's folder and started working there. Now again I had some kind of auxiliary file: I had 2 files, one from which I delete class methods I use, and one into which I write new methods I need to have.

Now I want to start using Git and I wonder: For all the project's text files, plans, diagrams, etc., it obvious - I keep them outside the Git repo. Whenever collaborative editing is needed I can set up a wiki or something like that. But for all those copies of the same header file, and for those auxiliary "marked" files, what do I do with them? I mean, it's fine by me to have them all in a branch, but what happens when I merge a branch into the trunk? I don't want to have all these copies and versions and lists, just the one final class file I've made.

On one hand, these are C++ source files used while coding. On the other hand they're not part of the pure source code of the software package, they just help me while I work but will never get compiled because in the end there's just the final version of the class which I chose to merge, and all other aux files, lists, etc. are kept just for reference.

What would be the best thing to do?
Thanks for reading my long story :)

EDIT: It's a local repo on my personal computer

Comment: Why not have plans etc in the repo? If they were, it would be easier to find the correct version of those. As for your other question, I'm not quite sure what you want, but you can change the way merging works by using a different merge strategy. I'd check "ours" and "theirs" if they are of any help. You could also have that stuff in a separate repo and include it as a subproject or something.

Comment: Actually, what I meant is to merge but exclude some of the files. I found a good solution for that: Every time before I merge, make a last "clean" commit with a message saying I've prepared the branch for merging, and then merge the branch after all aux files aren't there

Comment: If you just want to ignore the files, try a .gitignore file in the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the normal use of branches: You have your master branch ("official", if it where) and a branch to develop a new feature (it doesn't really have to live in a separate directory, if I understand you correctly). Periodically you synchronize the feature branch with the master, either by rebasing it on the master or merging its changes in. In its turn, you can well have subordinate branches in which you try out approaches to develop the feature, handled with respect to the feature branch just like that one respect to the master. But in that case you have to be careful whenever you rebase.

You should keep any data that isn't easy to recreate in the repository, be it source code, documentation or even design sketches. Stuff that can be recreated (object code, automatically formated documentation, ...) should be kept out (any change there will create a difference to be checked in). Your repository (particularly not published branches) is your own workspace, it can be all the messy you like.

Take a look at the book mentioned at the [git homepage](http://git-scm.com).

Answer (score 3):

Always keep documentation in same repository as source code. If you do not, your documentation will rot. It is becouse documentation is written agains some version of your software, so it has to develop the same way as software develops.

If your documentation is automaticaly generated or compiled into another format, commit only source data, makefile and configuration of generator, just like you do with source code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that’s clearly documentation and not source code, so you should separate it from your source code. As your documentation seems to be branch dependent, you should still check it into the repo, but in a separate `doc` directory.

About the merging: How a merge works is up to you in the end. Git just has a default merge strategy which is what most people want most of the time. But if you say that a merge into the main branch should just bring the code and not the docu, then that’s fine. Just merge that way:

```
git merge mybranch --no-commit
rm -rf **docu-dir**
git add -A
git commit
```

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it all out now. But now there's a new question: Can I add all my docs and ignore Makefile.am? I mean, if I just add these files to the repo without editing Makefile.am, will automake ignore them when configuring and building the binary? (which is what I want)

Comment: I have no experience with makefiles, but if you put your documentation in a separate folder, it should be easy to ignore